# Best place for notification preferences

Tags: information-architecture, notification, accounts, user-preferences, user-profile

Today I am working on a new feature inside our web app to allow users to set up their notification preferences. However, I am struggling to find an appropriate place to include this feature, which will be sent out by email.

The feature itself gives more control to users, who can subscribe to updates based on locations that they have access to manage. For example:

User X is a "Store Manager" of 10 different stores. He can create new locations, create new users, give them new roles and subscribe to status updates for each location.

My question is:

Should I include these preferences either inside "Profile Settings" or inside "My Stores" where the user can choose to subscribe to each store/location and define notification frequency?

- Below, you can see an example of this feature inserted into **My Account**:

[image: - Here can see an example of this feature inserted into My Account:]

- Below, you can see an example of this feature inserted into **Organization Account**:

[image: - Below, you can see an example of this feature inserted into Organization Account:]

Comment: I suppose the store manager has add/ edit privileges for each page/ section so it doesn't make sense to add all these actions in the profile section. "My Stores" is a better place for the notifications.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this belongs under your account. Maybe a general on/off toggle for these notifications belongs in your account, but not the specific store settings.

If you decide to place this feature under account, the user would have two places to see the stores, the regular page listing the stores (allowing multiple actions), and the user account listing the store (but only allowing one action) which would be confusing.

From a learning perspective, the user should only get one path to show the stores, not two.

Comment: Thanks @bart for your point of view. I haven't had thought from this perspective before. Although, I am not sure about the decision yet. Maybe, I will apply an A/B test to understand which version users have more preference. thx =)